# Posicionamento de imagem em div com drag and drop

Tags: jquery, imagem, upload, drag-n-drop

Bom dia, o que estou querendo fazer é, um sistema onde o usuário faça o *upload* de uma imagem e tenha uma pré-visualização de como ficará a imagem posicionada na `div`, podendo movê-la pra a posição que achar melhor.

É basicamente a mesma coisa que a atualização da capa do ***Facebook***, onde você faz *upload* de uma imagem e posiciona, através de *drag and drop*, da maneira que você quer!

Gostaria de saber se tem algum *plugin* *jQuery* para isso, ou se há alguma forma de fazer sem *plugin*, enfim, ideias? :)

Update:

O máximo que consegui, mas não obtive o resultado que queria, foi utilizando o *[plugin JCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Introduction)* para fazer algo parecido com o [exemplo de *preview*](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/tutorial3.html), mas como falei, não é bem isso que procuro, e sim o posicionamento direto na `div`, sem precisar de corte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei [este plugin em jQuery](http://puneetk.com/jq-image-drag), bem leve e fácil de usar (necessita do jQuery UI por causa do *drag*).

Pode inicializar ele assim:

```
$('#img').imagedrag({
    input: "#position" // output da position
    position: "middle" // posição inicial
});
```

Ele salva a *position* vertical da imagem quando é arrastada no parâmetro `input` do plugin.

Não sei o que tu pretende fazer depois, mas já vou deixar uma dica:
cria um `<input type="hidden" id="position">` para salvar o valor e depois tu pode salvá-lo num BD ou outro lugar para ajustar a posição quando o usuário voltar para aquela página, utilizando `background-position` do CSS ou o próprio parâmetro `position` do plugin.

Comment: Obrigado! Exatamente o que eu precisava.